# HERE WSE: FindPickup requiring optional "end" parameter?

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to use the FindPickup API of the HERE Waypoint Sequence Extension.

If I run the [sample code](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/topics/quick-start-pickup.html), everything is working fine.
But if I remove the "end" parameter from the query string, I'm receiving the error "required parameter end is missing".

However, the [API doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/topics/api-reference-findpickups.html) clearly states on several occasions that the "end" parameter is optional.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Richard and I'm a developer evangelist for HERE Technologies.

This is indeed an error in the documentation. I've let the team know and we will fix it. Thank you for pointing this is out!

To clarify: the *end* parameter is optional for the */findsequence* resource, but required for the */findpickups* resource.